# Issues returning a value in Scala inside an if statement

Tags: scala

I've got this 'if' condition inside a recursion function :

```
if (tmpList.size == 14) {
    val FBData =  Entry (tmpList(0), tmpList(1),tmpList(2),tmpList(3),tmpList(4),tmpList(5).toInt,tmpList(6).toInt,tmpList(7).toInt,tmpList(8).toInt,tmpList(9).toInt,tmpList(10).toInt,tmpList(11).toInt,tmpList(12).toInt,tmpList(13).toInt)
    if (index == lines.size - 1) {
        List(FBData)
    } else {
        val Data = pRecurrsioon(lines, index + 1) ++ FBData.toList
    }
}
```

When I runt this through a Scala compiler I get this issue:

31: error: type mismatch;
found   : Unit
required: List[HelloWorld.Entry]
}

I don't know why this keeps happening or how to fix it. Apparently im returning an Unsigned integer at some point but I can't see where.

Comment: `List(FBData)` has type `List[Entry]` but `val Data = ...` has type `Unit` (because you don't return anything from `else`, you just make an assignment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, the body of the `if` and the `else` do return values. The following is also valid (and still has your bug):

```
val ifResult = if (index == lines.size - 1) {
    //this works, and List(FBData) will be assigned to ifResult
    List(FBData)
} else {
    //this returns Unit as a result of the assignment operation
    val Data = pRecurrsioon(lines, index + 1) ++ FBData.toList
}
```

The compiler tries to assign to `ifResult` either the body of the `if` or the `else`. For this to work, it has to unify the types. This causes the error message you see, while checking the body of the `else` and trying to get the same type of it as from the `if`-body:

> 31: error: type mismatch; found : Unit required: List[HelloWorld.Entry] }